# Implement timer in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, timer

I am trying to implement a timer into my fragment. The timer works in a normal activity but not in a fragment. I have tried to define the view and then populate the view accordingly, on the actual app, the timer comes up but does not function. Any help would be appreciated. I have linked the original code that works in a normal activity and the fragment.
**Original Code, from the activity**

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;

    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private boolean mTimerRunning;

    private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });

        updateCountDownText();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
}
```

**Code for fragment**

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class AccessTimeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public AccessTimeFragment() {
    }

    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;

    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    View layoutView;

    private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_access_time, container, false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_access_time);

        mTextViewCountDown = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

        mButtonStartPause = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });

        updateCountDownText();
        return layoutView;
    }
    private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (layoutView.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_start_pause:
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button_reset:
                resetTimer();
                break;

        }
        updateCountDownText();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove these lines from fragment code -  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_access_time);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Just tried removing the lines of code and it works